# Remove trailing slash NGINX 2 sites one domain

Tags: nginx, configuration, rewrite

I have following NGINX config

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name www.cakein.local;

    rewrite_log on;


    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    #if (!-d $request_filename) {
    #    rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    #}

    location /en {

        alias /home/sites/cakein/en/webroot;
        index index.php

        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;

        location ~ ^/en(.*)\.php {

            index index.php;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1.php;
        }
    }


    location / { 

        root /home/sites/cakein/sk/webroot;

        index index.php index.html;

        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {

            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

so as you can see, there are two sites in following scheme:

```
sk
-- ...
-- webroot
en
-- ...
-- webroot
```

first site (sk) is hooked on '/' URI that works fine, 
domain.tld

but everything with "en" prefix fails.
domain.tld/en

There are two main problems with EN version

- "en" is redirected to "en/" how can i prevent this?
- URL rewriting does not work, so domain.tld/en/moribundus returns 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `alias` and `try_files` in the same `location` block can cause problems due to a [long standing issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

Also, your default behaviour is to send `/en/` to `/index.php`, which is the wrong URI and should be `/en/index.php`.

Try:

```
location /en {
    alias /home/sites/cakein/en/webroot;
    index index.php
    if (!-e $request_filename) { 
        rewrite ^ /en/index.php last;
    }
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

One possible way to fix the `/en` to `/en/` redirect is to add another `location` block:

```
location = /en {
    rewrite ^ /en/ last;
}
```

Comment: Richard, you are right thank you

 if (!-e $request_filename) .. solved my "nice urls", but still, NGINX is redirecting /en to /en/ :/

Comment: I edited my answer to address the other problem.

Comment: yeah, i applied your soluton but now i have problem with urls like /enthusiasm. So I've edited previous location "/en" to "/en/" and URLS like enthusiasm are ok, but problem is that all the stuff is pushed into index.php .. like css/something.css..

Comment: hm, I've added another rewrite right into /en location .. 

`
if ($request_uri ~ en[^/].+) {
    rewrite ^ / last;
}
`
@Richard Smith thanks for your help, you are my hero for next week :)